# Shortcut button on A fragment to perform programmatically an action defined in B without showing it on UI

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-play, fragment

I have 3 fragments : `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A` contents a list of element, when you chose an element from the list, it loads `B` fragment. Inside `B`, i have a button `showPreview`, a click on that button loads the `C` fragment.

I already implemented all of this, and it's working pretty nice.

Now what i want is to add, in `A` fragment, a `shortcut` button on each item, to access the preview (`C` fragment) without showing `B` fragment on UI like in `google play` application, you can download an app by clicking on Three dots -> Install, without opening app detail page.

[image]

Presently, when user clicks on `shortcut` button, i load the `B` fragment first (shown in UI), after i call `previewButton.performClick()` to click programmatically on the `showPreview` button. But that's not what i want because i am obliged to show `B` first, let it load entirely before making a `performClick()`.

I have read about [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) methods (attach/detach, add/remove etc.), about [fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), etc ... without solution.

So my questions are :

1. how can i load `B` fragment without showing it on the UI ?
2. If that's impossible, how to do the same thing as `google play` application ?

Comment: Separate model from view - both a and b change the model while only b displays the state.

Comment: i haven't understood @zapl, can you give more explanation please.

Comment: I understand know what you meant buy "seperate model from view", but that should be better if you explained a little ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue. My problem was that I haven't seperate `Views` from `Model`. I didn't have to use `performClick()` anyway, I didn't have to depend on `Button` click.

I resolved it by just creating a method which does nicely what I want, after I use this method on button click and after `shortcut list choice`.